# Deployed outlook 2007 add-in not shown in some of the targets machines/users

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

this `add-in` in this [Outlook 2007 Add-in Deployment as a DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486834/outlook-2007-add-in-deployment-as-a-dll) Post had the glory to be published to our domain users
every thing works fine except that the add-in not shown in some of the users accounts outlook's menu, instead the outlook shows it as `inactive application add-in`(the add-in is *COM add-ins type*)

I tried to reactivate it from `tools-->Trust Center-->Add-ins-->Manage COM Add-in`
but it back to be inactive every time I reactivate it?

What the point? am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any logging in the AddIn (perhaps to EventLog or similar) ?

Does the AddIn have any dependencies which are perhaps not present or not in the needed version ?

Any particular difference between the users where it works and the others like differnt permissions/Groups/OS version etc. ?

Comment: Originally I don't have any logging support in the add-in, I read somewhere that errors in code execution might prompt outlook to `automatically deactivate the add-in`, anyway; I added Event-viewer log support to the add-in; unfortunately the add-in after publish no longer works at all (all users) (maybe permission issue, but the sys admin said no policies applied to the event-viewer), I removed the logging support for event-viewer and write logging using `System.IO`, still waiting the publish to see the results.

Comment: regarding Groups, Permissions and OS version; all users have the same level, group and same OS version (XP SP2) except one or two users which they are already out of my scope.

Comment: latest news, the exception logging shows that the `mbox` we used to show any error was not working at all! so it was a problem with the permission over the connection we used inside the add-in (updated in one of the releases and causes the problem), thank you Yahia.